# Why does copper and zinc connected by a wire in 6.0M NaOH become a galvanic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

For an experiment I placed two electrodes of copper and zinc connected by a wire in 6.0M NaOH. According to standard reduction potentials, there should be no reaction; however, the copper becomes plated with zinc! There was also a measurable voltage across the two electrodes.

The hypothesized reactions (that are supposedly not favorable) are:

$$\ce{Zn(s) + 4OH^- <=> [Zn(OH)4]^2-(aq) + 2e^-} \textrm{   E}^\circ = 1.23 \textrm{V}$$
$$\ce{ [Zn(OH)4]^{2-}(aq) + 2e^- <=> Zn(s) + 4OH^-} \textrm{   E}^\circ = -1.23 \textrm{V}$$

So $\textrm{E}^\circ = 1.23 + -1.23 = 0$, and the reactions should not happen. Why do they?